# Ion-auth / An uncaught Exception was encountered / Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I am using codeigniter 3.x and ion-auth 2x.  Have a mini website going and I use github to manage the versions. The site works on my laptop but once I pull it to the ubuntu/apache webserver I get the below errors.  I have checked that all files are there and they are.  I have deleted the site and tried again - same result.  I am stumped!

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: RuntimeException
Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Ion_auth_model
Filename: /var/www/example.com/public_html/system/core/Loader.php
Line Number: 344
Backtrace:

File: /var/www/example.com/public_html/application/libraries/Ion_auth.php
Line: 62
Function: model

File: /var/www/example.com/public_html/application/core/MY_Controller.php
Line: 8
Function: __construct

File:     /var/www/example.com/public_html/application/controllers/Public_Controller.php
Line: 9
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/example.com/public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Always use first letter of a class to uppercase. As this is told here so many times should not be point to discuss anymore...Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Amazing.  Two days I have been working on this.  I changed the file name from ion_auth_model.php to Ion_auth_model.php and the error disappeared and the site is up.

Comment: Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries, drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner. Ionauth haven't been updated to codeignter 3 and has to be manually corrected. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html